# Can Office 365 Connectors be selectively enabled for Groups while currently off across a tenant

Tags: office365, office365connectors

I've been asked to investigate whether we can selectively enable connectors (all or specific) within Office 365 Groups using the API.

I've been unable to confirm this through my own searches. Has anyone else managed to do this and if so do you have an example of how it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present, it is not possible to selectively enable the connect for the groups programmatically. If you want to Office 365 REST API or Microsoft Graph to support this feature, you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).